# package data is not included in the package

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I have a project with a following structure. The executable is a package data file that I am trying to add to my package.

```
packagename
├── packagename.py
├── __init__.py
└── resources
    └── executable
```

In my setup file I added the executable to the package as follows.

```
package_dir={'packagename': 'packagename'}, 
package_data={'packagename': ['resources/executable',]},
```

I built the package locally with pip. I expected to find the executable in package.egg.info/SOURCES.txt but there is none.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong that prevents the package from being added to the package, or I am checking in the wrong place? I followed this [guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data).